# R grid package. Is there something like mgp in base R graphics?

Tags: r

I want to adjust the label position in the axis of R grid package, 
In base R I can do:

> par(mgp=c(...))

but I can't search it anywhere for **R grid package**.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data and code we can run to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Isn't it `help(gpar)` for graphical parameters in `grid`?

Comment: typically you'd use the `vjust` argument of the corresponding textGrob, but I'm not aware of a global option for this